# avoiding duplicate SWIG boilerplate when using many SWIG-generated modules

Tags: optimization, gcc, lua, swig, boilerplate

When generating an interface module with SWIG, the generated C/C++ file contains a ton of static boilerplate functions.  So if one wants to modularize the use of SWIG-generated interfaces by using many separately compiled small interfaces in the same application, there ends up being a lot of bloat due to these duplicate functions.

Using gcc's `-ffunction-sections` option, and the GNU linker's `--icf=safe` option (`-Wl,--icf=safe` to the compiler), one can remove some of the duplication, but by no means all of it (I think it won't coalesce anything that has a relocation in it—which many of these functions do).

My question:  I'm wondering if there's a way to remove more of this duplicated boilerplate, ideally one that doesn't rely on GNU-specific compiler/linker options.

In particular, is there a SWIG option/flag/something that says "don't include boilerplate in each output file"?  There actually *is* a SWIG option, `-external-runtime` that tells it to generate a "boilerplate-only" output file, but no apparent way of suppressing the copy included in each normal output file.  [I think this sort of thing should be fairly simple to implement in SWIG, so I'm surprised that it doesn't seem to exist... but I can't seem to find anything documented.]

Here's a small example:

Given the interface file `swg-oink.swg` for module `swt_oink`:

```
%module swt_oink
%{ extern int oinker (const char *x); %}
extern int oinker (const char *x);
```

... and a similar interface `swg-barf.swg` for `swt_barf`:

```
%module swt_barf
%{ extern int barfer (const char *x); %}
extern int barfer (const char *x);
```

... and a test main file, `swt-main.cc`:

```
extern "C"
{
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

extern int luaopen_swt_oink (lua_State *);
extern int luaopen_swt_barf (lua_State *);
}

int main ()
{
  lua_State *L = lua_open();
  luaopen_swt_oink (L);
  luaopen_swt_barf (L);
}

int oinker (const char *) { return 7; }
int barfer (const char *) { return 2; }
```

and compiling them like:

```
swig -lua -c++ swt-oink.swg
g++ -c -I/usr/include/lua5.1 swt-oink_wrap.cxx
swig -lua -c++ swt-barf.swg
g++ -c -I/usr/include/lua5.1 swt-barf_wrap.cxx
g++ -c -I/usr/include/lua5.1 swt-main.cc
g++ -o swt swt-main.o swt-oink_wrap.o swt-barf_wrap.o
```

then the size of each *xxx*`_wrap.o` file is about 16KB, of which 95% is boilerplate, and the size of the final executable is roughly the sum of these, about 39K.  If one compiles each interface file with `-ffunction-sections`, and links with `-Wl,--icf=safe`, the size of the final executable is 34KB, but there's still clearly a lot of duplication (using `nm` on the executable one can see tons of functions defined multiple times, and looking at their source, it's clear that it would be fine to use a single global definition for most of them).

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure SWIG doesn't have an option for doing this. I'm speculating now, but I *think* the reason might well be concern about visibility of this for modules built with different versions of SWIG. Imagine the following scenario:

Two libraries X and Y both provide an interface to their code using SWIG. They both opt to make the "SWIG glue" stuff visible across different translation units in order to reduce code size. This will all be well and good if both X and Y are using the same version of SWIG. What happens though if X uses SWIG 1.1 and Y uses SWIG 1.3? Both modules work fine on their own, but depending on how the platform treats shared objects and how the language itself loads them (`RTLD_GLOBAL`?) some potentially very bad things would happen from the combination of the two modules being used in the same VM.

The penalty of the code duplication is pretty low I suspect - the cost of swapping between VM and native code is typically quite high, which probably dwarfs the slightly reduced instruction cache hits, although it might be interesting to see real benchmarks. On the up side this is code no users ever need to worry about it, since it's all auto generated and all correctly kept with interfaces written for the corresponding version.

Comment: A good point.  I suppose it could be handled by including some sort of ABI-versioning in the names, but making everything static is certainly much simpler and less prone to mistakes.  Adding optimization does help reduce the overhead too: in a real-world case with optimization, it seems more on the order of about 4KB per object file; still a little bloat, but I suppose SWIG's never going to be really lightweight anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late, but here is a workaround:

- In SWIG (<= 1.3 ) there is `-noruntime` command-line option
- Since SWIG 2.0 `-noruntime` was deprecated, so now one should pass `-DSWIG_NOINCLUDE` to the C preprocessor - not to the swig itself

I am completely not sure that this is correct, but it at least works for me. I am going to clarify this question in the SWIG's mailing list.